# Is there a way to have typescript check for kvp validity in compile time

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to cross reference field id's with fieldDefinitions and then check them in validators. However since they're strings, they're easily wrong, is there a way to ensure a safe 1:1 mapping between dictionary types and their keys? Different components might have different fields.

```
type FieldDefinition = {
    [key: string]: string[]
};
```

Then i define my interface that i check in my custom form validator

```
const myField: FieldDefinition = {
    address: ['some_type'],
    city: ['some_type']
}
```

with an example of a functional component that's using those values

```
const ExampleForm: FC = () => {
return(
  <Form formId='someid'>
    <TextInput fieldId='address' />
    <TextInput fieldId='city' />
  <Form/>
);
}
```

The problem stems from the fact that the type is defined as string[] which can be anything, the field id's are consumed in the following form:

```
if (formData !== undefined) {
          formData.fieldDefinition[payload.value.key] = [
            ...payload.value.value
          ];
        }
      }
```

TL;DR
how do i define fieldid's so that they're a dictionary type (keys), but coded in a way that i could compile-time check them for validity.

Comment: If `payload.value.value` is *not* a string array, then you should get an error during compilation, as you're assigning a non-string array where a string array is expected. [Example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCIQGZwHZ2HAe2ygF4oBvAKChqgG0BrCEALigGdgAnHAcwF02nHtl51+lAL4BuSpQDGRTlACGQ7n3Gl6AIhU6ANFB0AjQ8fk7+sxdmUm22AK4BbExC5aydAIxGATEYAzNYKSsBQ8uoiYvzadAB0SSqhtsrI0Zpx3kkJJtZQAPSF8irYAOQRKuzscLzEKlDObh6qXFwqIHJpERjIPmzwSGiYOHiExGRUNDpMIDpsickSkt3hUH3+gwgo6Fi4+ETa08ZzC-S5+UUlZZWqNXUNTa7uXG0dXZJAA)

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my answer

```
export interface DefaultProps<K extends object> {
  formId: keyof K;
}
```

here is a working example where keys are checked
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-tharp-z9xkv
and here is a version with factory
https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-ellis-e2w1o